# Can parameter values depend on the rmarkdown output format?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Here's a simple example. I would like to show code, say, in html output but not in pdf. This doesn't work since parameters cannot be nested inside output formats in the YAML:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    params:
      showcode: true
  pdf_document:
    params: 
      showcode: false
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = params$showcode)
```
````

Is there a way to accomplish this in the YAML so I can click Knit to render multiple output formats (rather than having to write separate `rmarkdown::render()` statements)?

Comment: Untested, can you use `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = knitr::is_html_output())`? There is also the complementary `knitr::is_latex_output()` (for PDF output).

Comment: Clever. My two output formats are actually both `html`: `slidy_presentation` and `html_document`. (I should have made the example above more realistic.)

Comment: If you look at the source for `is_*_output`, it references `knitr:::pandoc_to`, which retrieves `opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")`, perhaps you can do a couple of test-knits to see what that looks like in each rendering format.

Comment: Perfect! That returns `html` for one and `slidy` for the other, so I can create an `is_slidy_output()` function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's also `is_html_output(excludes = "slidy")` https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-html.html